# Providing a third party with testable web services

Tags: web-services, testing, architecture, language-agnostic

The applications are as follows, seen from my point of view:

The application I am making (lets call it App1), and two third parties, App2 and App3.

- **App2**: Wants to consume simplified web services from App1
- **App1**: This is where I'm at. Services from App3 are handled nicely here already, with a nice, clean internal API for easy usage.
- **App3**: Third party service provider. Complex services. Important point: *Has no test environment, all we ever do against this is done with production data (although usually with a separate test account). If we screw up here, things happen to real people in the real world. This lack of a real test environment is not in my control.*

App3 provides my application, App1, with some web services. App2 wants me to "forward" those services in a simpler manner, so they don't have to reimplement the complexities I've already handled. But App2, which will be consuming my web services, needs to have a testable version of those services to use while implementing their side, to handle different use cases themselves.

#### How can this be implemented as smooth as possible?

Internally, the relevant parts of my existing application looks roughly like this:

- Presentation + web services (Web application + a small web API, and now also this Web Service)
- Service facades for services below (providing a clean API for the services App3 provide)
- Services (parsing, mapping, logging, some diagnostics for SOAP calls from App3) - sortof a "data tier"

The web service itself is fine, and would usually just be talking directly to the service facades. But that would leave App2 with only production data to test their services against (and this very service can't be tested on production data, it's a harsh write operation). So I could tell my IoC-container to use a separate implementation of the relevant service facade when, for example, a given config parameter is set. However, since I'm only going to "forward" a limited subset of these services, this would leave the rest of the application using that service facade unusable on our test environment, which would not be a good thing - other stuff needs to be tested (even against production data).

I'm thinking about introducing another tier between the presentation/Web service tier and the service facades, that only this web service use. Then let the IoC container dish up a test version of that when deploying to the test environment.

#### Good things about it:

- It lets me put all provided web services for third parties to consume in a completely testable state seen from the outside, where I can just if-else different stuff internally to simulate different use-cases.
- It enables the rest of the application to stay as-is, using actual production services from App3 where necessary elsewhere for testing.
- Will make both the testable and the "real deal" versions of this new tier unit testable

#### Bad things:

- Creating another layer of seemingly unnecessary complexity that's not *really* giving the application itself anything
- Requiring some mechanism for turning on/off test mode (= even more junk code/config)
- Junk-like code that people might mistake for being prototyping a year or two later, trying to get rid of it

Am I thinking the right thing, or are there other (noticably) different solutions to this?

- Send in a separate parameter to enable test mode? Seems risky and also like far more work on my side.

Answer (score 1):

> App2 [...] needs to have a testable version of those services to use
>   while implementing their side, to handle different use cases
>   themselves

It's not really clear what you want to test here.

If you mean testing `App2` plays well with `App1`, I tend to consider it's not a third party component's job to make itself "testable" - it's the consumer component that should test communication with the 3d party and verify if it can handle its results.

In `App2`, create a proxy to `App1`'s services. In your unit tests, you can stub the proxy's methods to return canned test data. These data can be more or less close to production data depending on the scenarios you want to cover. Then create integration tests between your proxy and the real services to verify everything runs smoothly.

Comment: While I agree on the theory that it's not my responsibility to be testable for external apps using my services, it's always really, really handy to have a full end-to-end test deployment. So practice sortof trumps theory here, in my opinion. 

And often it is easier to tell the service consumer that "if you call method X with value Y, you will get back error state Z", with all the different possible states, and let them handle it from there in their specific language, application or framework instead of me trying to explain it in text somewhere.

Comment: That's a good point, still I don't get the whole "introduce an additional tier between web service and Facade" thing. Why couldn't you ship this "contract test suite" with a fake Facade and still have integration tests for App1 that exercise against the real Facade ?

Comment: That new "middle tier" is there just because I'm only forwarding a very limited subset of the services my application consumes. And this middle tier would be the what I expose in my web services. The real facade is already covered with tests in my application. Edited original post.

Comment: I'm not sure an additional level of abstraction (and complexity) is really needed here. If it turns out your Facade doesn't have the appropriate granularity, split it in two parts - the "redirected to consumers" part and the "used here" part. Conversely, if you feel the Facade is cohesive as it is, keep it intact and just mock/stub the relevant parts in your shipped test. You made the conscious choice to have a large, coarse-grained collaborator by opting for a Facade. Trying to break this collaborator down now by creating a partial ersatz of it seems a bit... weird.

Comment: The services that are to be exposed to the outside aren't 1:1 with any form of structure internally, it's hand picked: only specific methods are to be forwarded (from the initial service I'm consuming that has ~40). Quite a large facade in terms of amout of functionality exposed, but it's a quite thin layer in itself - not much actually happens there.